# filter dataframe values based on another column using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Have df with values.

```
name     last_date                     submission_date

mike  2020-04-10 02:22:22.222   2020-04-01 02:22:22.222
mike  2020-04-10 02:22:22.222   2020-04-08 02:22:22.222
mike  2020-04-10 02:22:22.222   2020-04-16 02:22:22.222

ross  2020-04-16 02:22:22.222   2020-04-18 02:22:22.222
ross  2020-04-16 02:22:22.222   2020-04-19 02:22:22.222
ross  2020-04-16 02:22:22.222   2020-04-20 02:22:22.222
ross  2020-04-16 02:22:22.222   2020-04-15 02:22:22.222

carter 2020-04-22 02:22:22.222   2020-04-28 02:22:22.222
carter 2020-04-22 02:22:22.222   2020-04-15 02:22:22.222
carter 2020-04-22 02:22:22.222   2020-04-19 02:22:22.222
carter 2020-04-22 02:22:22.222   2020-04-21 02:22:22.222
```

filter values based on last_date. exclude values of submission_date if it is greater than last_date

expected output:

```
name     last_date                     submission_date

mike  2020-04-10 02:22:22.222   2020-04-01 02:22:22.222
mike  2020-04-10 02:22:22.222   2020-04-08 02:22:22.222

ross  2020-04-16 02:22:22.222   2020-04-15 02:22:22.222

carter 2020-04-22 02:22:22.222   2020-04-15 02:22:22.222
carter 2020-04-22 02:22:22.222   2020-04-19 02:22:22.222
carter 2020-04-22 02:22:22.222   2020-04-21 02:22:22.222
```

Comment: you can just `query`: `df.query("last_date>=submission_date")` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @anky  i need to exclude values of submission_date

Answer (score 1):

You can [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) the dataframe where `submission_date` is less than or equal to `last_date` , this returns the rows where the condition is met an filters out the rest:

```
df.query("last_date>=submission_date")
```

---

```
    name                 last_date         submission_date
0   mike   2020-04-10 02:22:22.222 2020-04-01 02:22:22.222
1   mike   2020-04-10 02:22:22.222 2020-04-08 02:22:22.222
2   ross   2020-04-16 02:22:22.222 2020-04-15 02:22:22.222
3  carter  2020-04-22 02:22:22.222 2020-04-15 02:22:22.222
4  carter  2020-04-22 02:22:22.222 2020-04-19 02:22:22.222
5  carter  2020-04-22 02:22:22.222 2020-04-21 02:22:22.222
```